# Disable checkout if products do not have same tag Shopify

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid, checkout

I have a product (tag contains 'starter-bracelet') in my store that must be sold with another linking product (tag contains 'bracelet-link'). Is there any way to block checkout if only the starter-bracelet product is in there and then allow checkout once the linked product is added?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which plan you are using in shopify?

Comment: @Onkar advanced shopify

Comment: You need to use 3rd party apps to restrict checkout when reqiurements doesn't meet.

Comment: @Onkar I've looked and can't find any so was looking to do it with code.

Comment: code doesn't helps you, there are direct checkout URL in Shopify that access checkout directly and rather then Shopify plus plan you don't have access to checkout.liquid file

Comment: @Onkar there must be a way to hide the checkout button based on product tags though right? Like I've said, I've looked for apps but can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort it, just needed to work out the correct logic.

```
        {% assign starter_bracelet = false %}
        {% assign nomination_link = false %}
        {% assign allow_checkout = true %}

        {% for item in cart.items %} 
          {% if item.product.tags contains 'starter-bracelet'%}
            {% assign starter_bracelet = true %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if item.product.tags contains 'link' %}
              {% assign nomination_link = true %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if starter_bracelet == true and nomination_link != true %}
              {% assign allow_checkout = false %}
              {% render 'nomination-checkout-message' %}
        {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to hide the checkout button. you need to edit the cart.liquid code for Shopify theme version 1, and respective section code for version 2 themes.

You need to add this code to the top and check for your tag

```
{% assign allow_checkout = true %} // By default checkout button show
{% for line_item in cart.items %} // loop over cart items 
  // if tag exist
  {% if line_item.product.tags contains 'starter-bracelet' %}
    // set it to false
    {% assign allow_checkout = false %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

// wrap you current checkout button inside this below `if` `else` condition

```
{% allow_checkout %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you for that but i also need it to allow checkout once 'bracelet-link' has also been added to cart.

So if 'starter-bracelet' - disable checkout
but if 'start-bracelet' and 'bracelet-link' - then allow checkout

Comment: when the desired product into the cart, it allows and shows the button on the cart page. this is liquid code and works only on page load